# How do you escape comments in markdown?

Tags: markdown

If I write `<date>` (without the `` ` `` back ticks) in markdown it disappears as markdown thinks I'm trying to write a comment. How can I make `<date>` appear in plain text, in markdown, without having to resort to back ticks? I tried escaping the `<` and `>` but that didn't help anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Syntax Rules](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#autoescape) mention this specifically:

> In HTML, there are two characters that demand special treatment: `<`
>   and `&`. Left angle brackets are used to start tags; ampersands are
>   used to denote HTML entities. If you want to use them as literal
>   characters, you must escape them as entities, e.g. `&lt;`, and
>   `&amp;`.

Therefore, you can do this:

```
&lt;date&gt;
```

which renders as

> <date>

As an aside, I remember the names of these entities by the names of the symbols. The letters `lt` and `gt` are acronyms for "**l**ess **t**han" and "**g**reater **t**han" respectively.